# How to stitch terrains together in Unity

Tags: unity, terrain

I'm building a world that consists of multiple terrains and I was wondering, how do I go about stitching them together so that features of my map will "fit" together?  I know Unity has the `SetNeighbors()` method, but it appears as though that simply tells each terrain which terrain is next to the other.  What I'm trying to accomplish is having multiple terrains and being able to have something like a mountain range move from one terrain to another and make it appear as though it's all one terrain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be what your looking for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8YAyGPhYpw
video explains a way of doing this I think. What I think you will need to do is export your terrains into highmaps and then edit them and re put them back in.